# resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js works on hybrid app?

Tags: sapui5

For sap-ui-core.js library to improve the performance if I add resources/sap-ui-cachebuster so as per the documentation the browser will store in cache memory.

But when we create a hybrid application so in that case will the library be stored in cache or every time it will load from server.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The SAPUI5 cachebuster mechanism will work for just fine for hybrid applications. If you follow the documentation, all the files taht you add to the cachebuster mechanism stay in the browser cache until they expire (you can set a maximum time period), or unless you change the files.